# Delete duplicate values from dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, arraylist

I need to delete the elements that are duplicated in a dictionary like this:

```
{
    0: array([506, 162]),
    1: array([507, 162]),
    2: array([506, 163]),
    3: array([506, 162]),
    4: array([506, 162]),
    5: array([507, 162]),
    6: array([506, 162]),
    7: array([507, 162]),
    8: array([509, 163]),
    9: array([509, 163]),
    10: array([506, 162]),
    11: array([507, 162]),
    12: array([509, 163]),
    13: array([509, 163]),
    14: array([508, 163]),
    15: array([509, 162]),
    16: array([509, 162]),
    17: array([506, 163]),
    18: array([507, 162]),
    19: array([509, 163]),
    20: array([509, 163]),
    21: array([509, 164]),
    22: array([509, 162]),
    23: array([510, 162]),
    24: array([510, 163]),
    25: array([511, 156]),
    26: array([511, 161]),
    27: array([543, 167]),
    28: array([515, 161]),
    29: array([515, 162]),
    30: array([545, 165]),
    31: array([506, 163]),
    32: array([507, 162]),
    33: array([509, 163]),
    34: array([511, 162]),
    35: array([510, 162]),
    36: array([515, 162]),
    37: array([546, 167]),
    38: array([512, 162]),
    39: array([546, 169]),
    40: array([516, 164]),
    41: array([516, 164]),
    42: array([516, 163]),
    43: array([517, 164]),
    44: array([517, 163]),
    45: array([227, 95]),
    46: array([516, 163]),
    47: array([517, 163]),
    48: array([516, 164]),
}
```

I tried with this code:

```
for key, centroide in ctrObjetosID.items():
if centroide in centroidesResult.values():
    continue
centroidesResult[key] = centroide
```

But I get an error

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Thanks for your help

Comment: it would be helpful if you could tell what is `array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code to the following:

```py
for key, centroide in ctrObjetosID.items():
    if len(centroidesResult.values()) == 0: # this check is necessary to prevent DeprecationWarning and make it save for future use
        centroidesResult[key] = centroide
        continue
    if ((centroide == np.asarray(list(centroideResult.values()))).sum(axis=1) == 2).any(): 
    # the equality comparision generates an elementwise boolean numpy array. 
    # The sum along axis 1 of this will generate an integer value for every entry in centroideResults
    # and if both centroide coordinates are matching the result in the appropriate row is 2
    # The any() checks at last, if any matching coordinates are found (rows with sum 2 are present).
        continue
    centroidesResult[key] = centroide
```